# Python printing values

Tags: python

How to print

```
1=1
1+2=3
1+2+3=6
.......
........
```

in python using for loop?

I already tried

```
    for i in range(1,int(n)+1):
        sum=0
        for j in range(1,i+1):
            sum=sum+j
            print("+",j,end=" ")
        print("=",sum)
```

Comment: What happened when you tried that? And which part of that was a problem? Also, please add just a bit more code, so that it can be run (currently `n` is undefined - how can we know that it is not actually `n` that has a problem?).

Comment: What output did you get with the code you tried?

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
values = list(range(1, n+1))
text = '+'.join([str(val) for val in values]) + '=' + str(sum(values))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input `n` is an integer, you can try something like this:

```
for i in range(1, n+1):
    print('{}={}'.format(
          '+'.join(str(j) for j in range(1, i+1)),
          sum(range(1, i+1))))
```

Comment: No access to Python, please comment if this doesn't work

Comment: It works like charm. Just in case you ever face again the need to check a `python` code without a local interpreter I recomend you to try [Pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) which gives you an online, shareable,  python shell.

Comment: Thanks! This will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
  for i in range(1,int(n)+1):
    sum=0
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        sum=sum+j
        if(j>1):
            print("+",end=" ")
        print(j,end=" ")
    print("=",sum)
```

This helped me

Answer (score 1):

This happens to be an interesting problem as it can be solved in many different ways.

Another simple solution using comprehensive lists would be defining the function `cumSumStr` as below code, which would do the work. Then you can just iterate and run the function as many times as you want as seen below.

```
def cumSumStr(n):
    numbers = range(1,n+1)
    return "+".join([str(s) for s in numbers]) + "=" + str(sum(numbers))

for i in range(1,4):
    print cumSumStr(i)
```

This code would print below result as you expected:

```
>>> 
1=1
1+2=3
1+2+3=6
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one not very different from already given answers:

```
sum = 0
for i in range(1, int(n) + 1):
    sum += i
    print(' + '.join(map(str, list(range(1, i+1)))), '=', sum)
```

Compute sum in the loop, so that we don't have to use `sum` function as the number of terms increases.